# about the difference between sparse partial least square (DA) in spls package and mixOmics

Tags: r

I have a question between parameter settings in sparse partial least square model.
In spls package, we need to specify eta, # of component.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spls/spls.pdf

```
data(mice)
# SPLS with eta=0.6 & 1 latent components
f <- spls( mice$x, mice$y, K=1, eta=0.6 )
# Calculate confidence intervals of coefficients
ci.f <- ci.spls(f)
# Corrected coefficient estimates
cf <- correct.spls( ci.f )
cf[20,1:5]
```

However, in mixOmics, we need to specify different parameters.

```
 liver.spls <- spls(X, Y, ncomp =10, **keepX = c(10,10,10), keepY= c(10,10,10)**, mode = "regression")
```

http://mixomics.org/case-studies/spls-liver-toxicity/

Could you tell me the difference between the two??